# extracting gradients for a model, reversing them and updating the weights in Keras

Tags: keras, gradient

I'm trying to do domain adversarial training using gradient-reversal procedure. I have a deep-learning model architecture consisting of 5 dense layers. Now I want to extract the gradient, reverse them and then update the weights. I am not sure how to extract the gradients and finally how to add them to update the weights. I have gone through some example codes but I am still pretty doubtful regarding using Keras backend. Any help with some toy code or example with explanation is really appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: Do you really need to get the gradients? Can't you just tweak the loss function to accomplish this?

Comment: @rvinas are you mentioning about giving loss_weights to be a suitable -ve integer???or else what do you mean by tweaking the loss function????

Comment: I mean flipping the sign, for example